# How to enable sublime text to take first line as file name while saving?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Earlier the Sublime used to take first line as file name by default but now it's "untitled". Is there a way to enable it or is there a plugin for that?

Thanks
[image: sublime-now]

Answer (score 13):

The first line is only used as the file name for unsaved files when the syntax is set to Plain Text. As soon as you change the syntax highlighting and type something, it will change the tab name to "untitled".

The implementation for this is in the Default package, `set_unsaved_view_name.py` file. To get it to work for all syntaxes:

1. Install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) through Package Control if it is not already installed
2. Open Command Palette
3. Type `PRV:` and select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
4. Select `Default`
5. Select `set_unsaved_view_name.py`
6. Find `if syntax != 'Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage':`
7. Select from there to the end of the `if` statement (the first `return` statement) (Python is indentation based) inclusive  `return` to be commented out.
8. Go to the Edit menu -> Comment -> Toggle Comment
9. Save the file
10. Ensure that, in your preferences (user, syntax specific etc.), `set_unsaved_view_name` is not set to `false`

Note: these instructions are valid as at ST build 3131, and the implementation could change in future builds.

Comment: thanks, but it didn't worked for me. I made a video to demonstrate that https://youtu.be/gLHQoIEbb4Y

Comment: hmm, do you perhaps have `set_unsaved_view_name` set to false in your preferences somewhere? you could try adding `print('set_unsaved_view_name.py - at line 35')` style statements and check ST's console to help debug where it is going wrong

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me on ST3, build 3126. For files that were already open and had "untitled" as their tab name, I did have to make a change to the first line content for the tabs to update (e.g., adding and removing a space). (Also, for awkwardly long tab names, you can type view.set_name("the new name") in the console to change the tab name.)

Comment: Perfect! Worked for me as well! This is why I love sublime! it's so hackable!

Comment: Worked in Sublime 3. Thank you so much!